# Java Android - How to call onSuccess method

Tags: java, android, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm really new to Java & Andoid, I used to code in Swift.

I'm currently coding the register activity, and more precisely, I'm coding a method to add user data in Cloud Firestore.

In swift I coded something like that:

```
func signupUser(firstname: String, lastname: String, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void) {

      REF_USERS.document(uid).setData([
         "firstname": firstname,
         // etc..
      ]) { (err) in
         if let err = err {
            print("Error adding document: \(err)")
         } else {
            // THE FUNCTION HERE
            onSuccess()
         }
      }
   }
```

I would like to have the same "onSuccess()" method in Android, but I don't know how to do it...

I searched but I didn't find anything ...

This is my code without the onSuccess():

```
public void addNewUser(String firstname, String lastname, String email, Integer gender, String uid, String profileImageUrl){

        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("firstname", firstname);
        data.put("lastname", lastname);
        data.put("email", email);
        data.put("gender", gender);
        data.put("boxId", "independent");
        data.put("notificationsEnabled", true);
        data.put("profileImageUrl", profileImageUrl);

        mFirebaseFirestore.collection("users").add(data)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot written with ID: " + documentReference.getId());
            }
        })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e);
                    }
                });

    }
```

Comment: "without the onSuccess"... you have onSuccess registered to the onSuccessListener after .addData(). Is that not working as intended? What is it doing when you run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called `callback` in java.

First, you define the callback interface with desired functions and input.

```
public interface FooOnSuccessListener {
    void iWantToPassOutAnInteger(int passItOut);
}
```

Next, in your `addNewUser` method, passin this interface as imput and call it to pass your data

```
public void addNewUser(String someInput, final FooOnSuccessListener listener){

    mFirebaseFirestore.collection("users").add(data).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
            listener.iWantToPassOutAnInteger(FromYourFirebase.someInteger);
        }
    });

}
```

Finally, let's say your `addNewUser` method comes from class Foo. You can then do something like:

```
Foo.addNewUser("some param", new FooOnSuccessListener() {
    @Override
    public void iWantToPassOutAnInteger(int passItOut) {
        //Do something with param passItOut
    }
});
```

Comment: Do I have to use a static function for addNewUser(), in order to call it like that Foo.addNewUser() after?

Comment: @KevinB You need to design that by yourself. I'm just giving an example. And yes, you will need that to be static for my code but you can also try creating the Foo object and then call the function without making it static

Comment: Do I need to create an interface each time I want to create a new callback? Given that I can have a lot a callbacks it will be a nightmare

Comment: @KevinB Well technically you can reuse but for better syntax, reading purpose I suggest you to create new ones. Again this is also on you

Comment: @KevinB the most important thing is that you understand what you are writing and make it easier for future maintainance